# create a custom LLVM attribute

Tags: attributes, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to create a custom attribute that marks a function in case if certain condition is met. As a first step I included below code in Attr.td file

```
def myattribute : InheritableAttr {

  let Spellings = [GCC<"myattribute">];
  let Subjects = SubjectList<[Function]>;
  let SimpleHandler = 1;
  let Documentation = [Undocumented];

}
```

as well as this code in SemaDeclAttr.cpp file

```
case ParsedAttr::AT_myattribute:

    handleSimpleAttribute<myattributeAttr>(S, D, AL);

    break;
```

but when i try to use this in the pass it gives me following error

```
error: ‘myattribute’ is not a member of ‘llvm::Attribute’
```

i am new to llvm could anyone tell me whats happening???

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the spelling, have you tried using `AT_Myattribute` instead of `AT_myattribute`?